# Codeigniter mysql db connection with Amazon RDS failing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, amazon-rds

I am having the worst time with this after searching for hours and hours.

My connection to Amazon RDS credentials are correct, however, I cannot pull any data and I get a 500 error from the following.

I've made this in the most raw of coding to avoid any CI mistakes, On my model I have:

```
class Foreclosure_model  extends CI_Model {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

     $this->db = $this->load->database('aws');

}

function get_sql_results($state,$county){

return $this->db->query("select State, County from foreclosure_properties     where State = 'CA' AND County = 'del norte'");
 }
}
```

Then on my controller I have:

```
$this->data['listings'] = $this->foreclosure_model->get_sql_results($state,$county);
```

on my aws connection information I have:

```
$db['aws']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
$db['aws']['username'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$db['aws']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$db['aws']['database'] = 'xxxxxx_xxxxxx';
$db['aws']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['aws']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['aws']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['aws']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['aws']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['aws']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['aws']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['aws']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['aws']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['aws']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['aws']['port'] = 3306;
```

I have tried doing this exact same connection directly with Navicat to test the sql connection and query, it works successfully.  I cannot seem to get this to run in Codeigniter.

The result when run on Codeigniter is a 500 error.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting `$state` and `$county` from a POST request ?
if yes check whether `CSRF` is enabled or not.

Comment: yes $state and $county from post inside the function if just 'echo' will work fine, CSRF is disabled.  I'm really stuck :/

Comment: Also, this is a second database connection if it helps.  This is not the primary database, we're connecting to $db['aws']; not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: is the Codeigniter framework sitting on AWS? making connections from Navicat isn't going to do much since its a desktop mysql gui client and its connection from that location. Create a simple .php file and make the db connection to make sure there aren't any server issues. in addition, check your AWS security group to make sure you're allowed to make connection from the originating server to the RDS. Furthermore, you need to make sure you're making a simple connection from the server where the CodeIgniter sits to the RDS db.

Comment: add this code `$query = $this->db->query(..); return $query->result();` in your model

Comment: are you running your application from the localhost?

Comment: change in php.ini `display_errors = on` for showing the error instead of `500` response

Answer (score 0):

As you're using more than one connection, you'll want to pass in a second parameter of 'TRUE' to return the database object.

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('aws', TRUE);
```

If you don't pass this, then the database object is not returned and therefor you can't call any of the functions (such as get(), query() etc).

You can read more about multiple connections here:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on!

Note: It may be worth mentioning it may make things easier if instead of assigning the database to $this->db, you chose another name such as $this->aws_db as then you're not overwriting the $this->db object for your default database. Probably not a big issue, but may make it easier to troubleshoot as your project grows.